# MS Word VBA macro to search and replace (Regex)

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

Suppose a word file contains

```
ab{cdefg{hij{k
```

And I want { to be moved one place to the right like

```
abc{defgh{ijk{
```

I need to make an array with all characters then run a loop with Regex search and replace

search:

```
({)(array[index])
```

replace:

```
$2$1
```

Plain Regex without loop won't work because I'm dealing with Indic text which have complex characters. I've done this on JavaScript and ExtendScript in inDesign, but I've no clue about VB. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you describe how the Indic text affects things? For example, is part of the problem that some Indic characters are expressed in Word as 2 characters and a swap will only move the "{" one character instead of 2. Or what?

Comment: Yes. Certain indic conjuncts which appear as one letter and in real life are treated as one letter are actually cluster of 2-5 letters in Unicode.

Comment: My (rahter obvious) suggestion. If Word's Find/Replace can't cope with the texts you are dealing with, forget regex, and focus on the fact that the Word object model (and VBA) is concerned, sees your document as a sequence of  Word Character objects that can be indexed 1..etc. Then you need to iterate through the character sequence looking for "{" (and possibly ignoring "{" characters that are part of some special Indic character sequence, though I doubt that will occur), then examine the following characters and determien how many Unicode characters you need to move the "{".

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a Word wildcard search-and-replace:

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
    .Text = "(\{)(?)"           ' find opening brace followed by a single character
    .Replacement.Text = "\2\1"  ' swap positions
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: That does nothing. Found the following code elsewhere that does normal search and replace but won't handle Regex

`With ActiveDocument.Content

    With Selection.Find  
        .Text = ChrW(&HB47) & ChrW(&HB2C)  
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(&HB2C) & ChrW(&HB47)  
        .Forward = True  
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue  
        .Format = False  
        .MatchCase = False  
        .MatchWholeWord = False  
        .MatchWildcards = True  
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _  
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue`

Comment: @coldbreeze16: My code woks on your sample text. It seems you have might have different input? Can you post that?

Comment: why does everyone who sees word vba with regex automatically go to wildcards? They're not the same; regex is far more powerful. why not assume someone who asks for regex wants regex and is aware that wildcards exist? You cannot, for example, do multi-line matching with word wildcards.

Comment: @A.Eakins The issue here is that the Word API does not support a powerful regex search and replace functionality. Using wildcard search is the best you get from Word. What you could do though is extract the text, do regex matching on the text, find the matched texts in the Word document and replace these texts programmatically. This is non-trivial, error-prone and something you would have to code yourself as it is not offered by Word.

Comment: You're right in that it's non-trivial. It's quite difficult. I've been struggling with it myself, I just get frustrated when searching for using RegEx with visual basic and everyone says: "Use wildcards", and in most cases it makes more sense, but not in all of them.